# Locking the scale while resizing the panels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, scale, mapcanvas

QGIS changes map canvas scale while resizing the panels. I use `iface.mapCanvas().setScaleLocked(True)` to lock the scale.

Is there a manual option to lock the scale in "Settings"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's what the lock icon next to the scale does.

[image]